# Variable argument passing in C to printf / vsprintf

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to pass variable arguments that I get to another function I call. 
I had written a sample code to test this. 
Why is my_printf working but not my2_printf in below code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

my2_printf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
  va_list ap; 
  va_start(ap, fmt);
  printf(fmt, ap);
  va_end(ap);
}

my_printf(const char *fmt, ...)
{
  va_list ab; 
  va_start(ab, fmt);
  vfprintf(stdout, fmt, ab);
  va_end(ab);
}

main()
{
  int i = 5;
   my_printf("This is a test %d =>  %s\n", i, "done");
   my2_printf("This is a test %d =>  %s\n", i, "done");
}
```

Output I get is as below:

```
This is a test 5 =>  done
This is a test -171084944 =>
```

Comment: I have a feeling you are using wrong signature. Take a look at the list of different signatures and make sure you are using the right one: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there's variant of [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) that expects a `va_list` argument. If you have a `va_list` you *must* use the functions with the `v` prefix, such as [`vprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf).

The call to `printf` leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Thanks.. Using vprintf instead of printf did work. That does answer my question. I will upvote. But does not really solve my problem as I need to pass this to syslog() as well. How do I do that if not necessarily using a va_list asgument.

Comment: @HarithGeorge Use `vsnprintf` to "print" into a buffer that you can then pass along to e.g. `syslog`.

Comment: @HarithGeorge Or if you're on a Linux system you could use [`vsyslog`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/vsyslog.3.html).